# How to include CDATA parameter into a C# soap call

Tags: c#, soap, cdata

I have a soap client and in order to make a call to a service of my company I need, among others, a parameter containing a CDATA string.

Simple version of the C# code I have is the following:

```
ServiceRef.GetArraySoapClient client = new ServiceRef.GetArraySoapClient();

String codes = @"
<Codes>
  <Code><Batch>AAA</Batch><Item>YYY</Item></Code>
  <Code><Batch>BBB</Batch><Item>XXX</Item></Code>
</Codes>";

client.GetArray("uname", "pword", "<![CDATA[" + codes + "]]>");
```

When I did the same using SoapUI, it works. But within the C# code, it gives me an error that goes like "error in the format of Code items".

I don't understand what is wrong with defining CData like this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently I don't need to add something special before and after 'codes' while sending the request.